# Create SQL view based on condition

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-view

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sql view from a table which one of its column contains both string of characters and json format( it has `varchar` as data type). The column in some rows contains only characters(`e.g.32564` ) and in the other rows contains json data. How can I create **a view** based on this column that if column1 has json stored inside it then :

```
create view dbo.vTable1
select 
...
from dbo.Table1
cross apply openjson(...) with (...)
cross apply openjson(...) with (...)
```

Otherwise :

```
create view dbo.vTable2
select 
...
from dbo.Table1
```

(I don't want to use stored procedure)

Comment: *"This column in some rows contains only number(e.g.32564) and in the other rows contains json."* Sounds like you have denormalised data and it's the table that needs fixing. If the column contains both JSON data *and* "numerical", the latter by definition *cannot* be a numerical; `'32454'` is *not* a number it's a string. Fix the design, then you don;'t have the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Larnu. However, check the ISNUMERIC function. That might help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql

Comment: @GrantFritchey `ISNUMERIC` is a flawed function at best; `TRY_CONVERT` would be a far better option. This is especially true is the OP wants to consume the data as a numerical value, and not a string (and thus not get results like `'40'` having a greater value than `'32564'`).

Comment: @Larnu Column1 has varchar as data type.

Comment: I think you completely missed my point @Florentina ; that is a problem. `'32564''` **isn't** a number, it's a string. If you need to store numbers, then use a numerical data type; perhaps `int`. Don't mix data types in a single column. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: While the table design is suboptimal (and it is better to fix source instead of applying a band aid) the IsJson function might help to differentiate between rows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution compiled from the comments.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  id int,
  value nvarchar(100)
);

insert into data (id, value) values
(1,
'{
  "Key1": 100,
  "Key2": "One hundred"
}'),
(2,
'{
  "Key1": 200,
  "Key2": "Two hundred"
}'),
(3, '300'),
(4, '400'),
(5, 'Five hundred'),
(6, 'Six hundred');
```

**Solution 1**

In case you want to return numeric data.

```
create view idNumberView as
select d.id,
       jv.result
from data d
cross apply openjson(d.value) with (result int '$."Key1"') jv
where isjson(d.value) = 1
  union all
select d.id,
       convert(int, d.value)
from data d
where try_convert(int, d.value) is not null;
```

**Result 1**

```
id  result
--  ------
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
```

**Solution 2**

In case you want to return string data.

```
create view idStringView as
select d.id,
       jv.result
from data d
cross apply openjson(d.value) with (result nvarchar(20) '$."Key2"') jv
where isjson(d.value) = 1
  union all
select d.id,
       d.value
from data d
where try_convert(int, d.value) is null
  and isjson(d.value) = 0;
```

**Result 2**

```
id  result
--  ------------
1   One hundred
2   Two hundred
5   Five hundred
6   Six hundred
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=339ec7fc3a83eb1a531d39dce32d0292) to see both solutions in action.